# Can I grow coffee plants in my garden?

Tags: indoors, plant-care, container-gardening

I live in the Netherlands, where the climate is very unstable. Whilst I love my coffee and love doing a lot of stuff myself, the urge to grow my own coffee had risen. I was wondering if the Dutch climate makes for good coffee / coffee plants.

Comment: My guess is that given that coffee is a high altitude tropical plant, maybe not... but this is more a question for the gardening site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coffee is considered a [tropical plant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffea) and is not going to overwinter in the Netherlands.  It makes a good house plant but there are some obstacles between you and a cup of coffee you grew and processed yourself.

- a plant capable of fruiting is two to three meters tall
- it is usually three to five years old before flowering and producing beans
- the beans can take nine months to ripen on the plant
- under good cultivation one tree can produce one to two kilograms of beans a year depending on variety

More notes about cultivation are found [here](http://www.justaboutcoffee.com/?file=coffeetree):

> Important growing factors are:
>
> Avoiding excessive cold and heat.
>
> 1200-1500mm of rain per annum.
>
> A few hours of light per day.
>
> No strong winds.
>
> Altitude - The higher the better.

The last might be the most challenging for growing coffee in the Netherlands.

Comment: Sounds like something that's very hard to accomplish but still doable. I'm not very fond of robusta beans due to their muddy taste so I think I will go with arabica in this case. Unless robusta is a more friendly plant. Doe you happen to know some sort of robusta that mimics the taste of a arabica bean?

Answer (score 2):

While you can [grow coffee at home](http://www.gurneys.com/grow_your_own_coffee), you are almost certainly not going to be able to grow it outdoors in the Netherlands. Coffee tends to only [grow well](http://www.nationalgeographic.com/coffee/map.html) in fairly mountainous equatorial regions with moderate temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start seeds and grow them in a container this year? You can bring it inside before cold weather threatens and take it with you when you move. I am pretty sure coffee plants are zone 10. I saw one in the Logee's Greenhouse catalog the other day and thought it would be cool to grow one, but then came to my senses and decided I wouldn't want one more plant that I had to overwinter inside.

I've linked the coffee plant page from Logee's because it tells you a tiny bit about the temps and conditions the coffee plants need.

Here is a link that might be useful: [Coffee Plant](http://www.logees.com/Coffea-arabica-Coffee/productinfo/R1180-2/)